# Chrome not fully parsing CDN

Tags: google-chrome, cdn, gist

I have been having issues in `Chrome` with some of my CDN's I created using `Github` and `Staticaly`.

As you can see, the code from the CDN has been cut off at a seemingly random line (and right in the middle of it). Does anyone know why this is happening?

Full CDN here: https://cdn.staticaly.com/gist/moofawsaw/183c5d89d85296bb490278f53fd289d3/raw/540b06cc7aabceecd1fd9fa5fa8e06f911b4e4de/pairpal-wish.js

[image: As you can see, the code from the CDN has been cut off at a seemingly random line (and right in the middle of it)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's Frans from Staticaly. This issue was detected under our side and not Chrome, and already resolved by our team. Let me know if you have any questions.